# Import from XSLX to database using BizTalk Server 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am trying to create a sample app using `BizTalk Server 2013` that takes data from a `XLSX` file and saves them to a Sql Server database.
I know that this can be done very fast using `DTSX` files but I need it with `BizTalk`. 
I tried creating a `Custom Pipeline` and use it as a decoder but I failed to finish it.
Can someone provide me a simple example how can I manage this?

Comment: Is the XLSX file XML-based or binary? (to see this, open it in notepad)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have option to convert the excel to csv format. If yes then convert the file to csv and then use it in BizTalk to generate a flat file schema and then you can use flat file disassembler.

If csv is not an option then you can use Excel OLEDB provider for .NET to get the data from excel in a custom pipeline component.

Or You can look at some open source pipeline components http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11679.biztalk-list-of-custom-pipeline-components.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i agree with Vikas and if you have to create a custom pipeline component take a look at the article i just create to develop custom component :

http://boutalebhicham.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/developing-biztalk-custom-pipeline-component/